# степень Бакалавра/бакалавра

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`Он получил-таки степень Бакалавра/бакалавра.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Бакалавр вырос из абитуриента, затем студента, ну и дослужился до нижней ступени высшего образования — аж сам бакалавр!

Но какие уж тут прописные? Даже аспирант, кандидат и доктор наук со строчной... 8-(

---

[Бакалавриат, специалитет и магистратура являются уровнями профессионального высшего образования, отличающимися по содержанию и продолжительности обучения. Для освоения программ бакалавриата или специалитета необходимо иметь среднее общее образование, для программ магистратуры - высшее образование. В дальнейшем бакалавр может продолжить обучение и получить степень магистра.](https://www.consultant.ru/edu/student/consultation/bakalavr_specialist_magistr/)